# retrieve data from 3 tables How to retrieve data from the last table using the first one in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have three table:

**Teacher**

id

name

family_name

**ClassRoom**

class_name

teacher_id

**Student**

name

family_name

Teacher have one to many relation with ClassRoom

Student have many to many relation with ClassRoom

how can i retrieve all Students of a Teacher using Eloquent methods without using foreach?

Comment: This is in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$teacher = Teacher::with('classrooms.students')->find($someId); //eager load
$studentsArray = $teacher->classrooms->pluck('students'); //array of students with duplicates
$students = (new Collection($studentsArray))->collapse()->unique(); //collection of unique students
```

Comment: BadMethodCallException with message 'Method lists does not exist.

Comment: Try pluck('students') instead lists

Answer (score 0):

in your teacher model create a new relation like below:

```
public function students()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Student::class, ClassRoom::class);
}
```

now you just query the student like below:

```
$teacher = Teacher::where('id', '1')->first();
$students = $teacher->students;
```

Comment: hasManyThrouh only used for three tables with one to many relations i have one to many and many to many